# Render Button as Loading Sign in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend, react-typescript

**Description:**

I have a button in a form. When the button is clicked, the form is submitted to a backend. While the request is in flight, I'd like the button to show a loading signal instead of the usual text. When the request is done, I'd like the form to disappear.

I can do this with useState for the different button forms, but my issue is that just before the form disappears, the text shows again. This is a small issue but it looks unpolished.

**Issue:**

When the button is clicked, the loading animation appears as intended. When the request finishes, I can see the text re-appear for a split second before the dialog disappears. I don't want the text to reappear until I reopen the dialog.

**What I tried:**

I currently change the loading state back to false after I call (and wait on) closing the dialog. I tried NOT doing that, but this causes the loading button to be there when I reopen the dialog, which is worse.

To correct that, I tried setting the value of the loading state to false on startup, as follows:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(false);
}, []);
```

this had no effect, which leads me to believe that the component only gets mounted once, and that when I close it it doesn't actually get unmounted.

I tried using the `LoadingButton` component from `material-ui/lab`, but for a variety of typescript/react reasons it was just throwing errors left and right. Since it's an experimental package I decided to stay away from it.

**Code:**

Here is my component:

```js
export const NewClientDialog = (props: INewClientDialogProps) => {
  // open is a boolean that's true when the dialog is open, close is a function that closes the form dialog
  const {open, close} = props;
  const [fn, setFn] = useState("");
  const [ln, setLn] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [pn, setPn] = useState("");
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState<INewClientProps>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  // this is not optimal, but not the point of this post. It sets the object from the form inputs for the network request
  useEffect(() => {
    const newClient: INewClientProps = {
      firstName: fn,
      lastName: ln,
      email: email,
      phoneNumber: pn
    }
    setNewUser(newClient)
  }, [fn, ln, email, pn])
  
  // this gets triggered when a button is clicked
  const onAddClient = () => {
    // set the loading animation
    setLoading(true)
    // this calls the network API and returns a promise
    createNewClient(newUser)
    // once the promise is completed, close the dialog
    .then(() => close())
    // then set the loading back to false
    .then(() => setLoading(false))
  }

  // this the button, if loading is true then it is a circular loading icon otherwise it's text
  const AddClientButton = () => {
    const contents = loading ? ><CircularProgress /> : <div>Create new client</div>
    return (
      <Button onClick={() => onAddClient()}>
        {contents}
      </Button>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog onClose={close} open={open}>
        <TextField label="First name" onChange={(value) => setFn(value.target.value)}/>
        <TextField label="Last name" onChange={(value) => setLn(value.target.value)}/>
        <TextField label="Email address" onChange={(value) => setEmail(value.target.value)}/>
        <TextField label="Phone number" onChange={(value) => setPn(value.target.value)}/>
        <AddClientButton />
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just after writing it, I had an epiphany:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, [open]);
```

this does exactly what I want it to do - when the dialog is open, set loading to false. I removed the `setLoading(false)` call in `onAddClient`.

I will leave this up, hopefully it helps anyone who wants to create dynamic buttons in Material UI.